# how to add new firebase emulators to my existing project?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-pubsub

so I already have some firebase emulators running on my project (auth, functions and firestore emulators).

if I run `firebase emulators:start` then I will have this 2 messages in my terminal

> i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore

> ⚠ functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these
> services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database,
> hosting, pubsub

now I want to add pubsub emulator to my current project, how to do that? I  use NodeJS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just open your `firebase.json` file and then you can add or remove the value in the json file as you need

`firebase.json` file is located in the same hierarchy as your `functions` folder (outside your `functions` folder)

see the documentation [in here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#configure_emulator_suite)

```
"emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": "8080"
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,      
      "port": 4000         
    },
    "auth": {
      "port": "9099"
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": "5001"
    },
    "database": {
      "port": "9000"
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": "5000"
    },
    "pubsub": {  // add this if you want to add pubsub emulator
      "port": "8085"
    }
  }
```

the CLI will then automatically download the emulators after you run `firebase emulators:start`

Answer (score 2):

`firebase init emulators`

Runs the wizard to set up your wizard. Hit enter a bunch of times for the default ports.

[image]

That injects into your firebase.json file

[image]